# Handle a COM event in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com

I am controlling an application via its COM server from PowerShell. This is pretty simple:

```
# Start the application via COM
$app = New-Object -ComObject CoolApp.Application

# Start a data measurement in the application
$measurement = $app.Measurement
$measurement.Start()
```

Now comes the hard part: the Measurement object has an event called "OnFinished", that is invoked when the data measurement is done. I would like my powershell script to wait for the occurence of this event.

How can I subscribe to such an COM event PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

If a Primary Interop Assemblies(PIA) is provided from the developer to the COM object you are using, you can easily register event handlers by using it.

For example, refer to this description.
[Registering and Catching Communicator 2007 Automation API Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/lync-2010/hh243700(v%3Doffice.14)#registering-and-catching-communicator-2007-automation-api-events)

Like the above components and Office, PIA is provided for many of Microsoft's products.
[Office primary interop assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2017)

If there is no PIA, you can request it from the developer or you can create it yourself.
The way to make it is explained on this page.
[How to: Generate Primary Interop Assemblies Using Tlbimp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-generate-primary-interop-assemblies-using-tlbimp-exe)

Answer (score 0):

Is OnFinished a property of the app or measure object? If it is, and it returns a value when queried you could use a while loop to wait for that returned value to be a specific value e.g. if that property returns 'Completed' once the process has finished:

```
while($measure.OnFinished -ne 'Completed')
{
    Sleep 5
}
```

Difficult to be more specific with my answer as I am not familiar with your COM object :)